# Как создать новую колонку категорий по ключевым словам в другой колонке?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas, dataframe, текст

Колонка `plot_keywords` содержит ключевые слова, характеризующие сюжет фильма. На основе данных этой колонки надо создать колонку `movie_plot_category`, которая содержала бы 4 категории в зависимости от ключевых слов в колонке:

- Категория "love_and_death", если ключевые слова содержат и ключевое слово "love" и ключевое слово "death";
- Категория "love", если ключевые слова содержат ключевое слово "love";
- Категория "death", если ключевые слова содержат ключевое слово "death";
- Категория "other", если ключевые слова не соответствуют перечисленным выше условиям.

Так не работает:

```
m = []
for element in data['plot_keywords']:
    m.append(re.findall(r'\blove\b', element))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [26]: df
Out[26]:
               plot_keywords
0                love, death
1              lovely, drama
2            death, thriller
3  sci fiction, utopia, love
4     love, death, ice cream
```

решение:

```
love = df["plot_keywords"].str.contains(r"\blove\b")
death = df["plot_keywords"].str.contains(r"\bdeath\b")

df.loc[love, "movie_plot_category"] = "love"    
df.loc[death, "movie_plot_category"] = "death"
df.loc[love & death, "movie_plot_category"] = "love_and_death"    
df["movie_plot_category"] = df["movie_plot_category"].fillna("other")
```

альтернативное решение с использованием [np.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
love = df["plot_keywords"].str.contains(r"\blove\b")
death = df["plot_keywords"].str.contains(r"\bdeath\b")

df["movie_plot_category"] = \
    np.where(love & death,
             "love_and_death",
             np.where(love,
                      "love",
                      np.where(death,
                               "death", 
                               "other")))
```

результат:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
               plot_keywords movie_plot_category
0                love, death      love_and_death
1              lovely, drama               other
2            death, thriller               death
3  sci fiction, utopia, love                love
4     love, death, ice cream      love_and_death
```